# IIS creating a web site

Tags: iis, iis-7

I'm trying to add a new web site on my IIS manager.

-> My site name is "teorikolarak.com"

-> Application pool is  "DefaultAppPool"

-> Physical Path is "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\teorikolarak.com"

teorikolarak.com is a file and it contains "default.html" page.

When I click the Test Settings... button it does not return any error. Everyting seems to okey .

-> binding type: http

-> IP adress : 192.168.2.4

-> Port:80

-> HostName: www.teorikolarak.com

Also I updated hosts file.  "192.168.2.4      teorikolarak.com"

Now, when I type the www.teorikolarak.com on address bar It can not found the site. Also, I typed the 192.168.2.4 on address bar, default IIS7 page is opening. why is it happens? why my default.html file doesnt appears on my browser?

Windows7 & IIS7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the website in IIS Manager and then press the Explore button in the Actions panel.  Do you see your default.html file?  If so, double click on the "Default Document" feature (in the middle panel).  Check to see if Default.html is listed as a valid default document.  It probably is not.  Click the Add... button in the Actions panel to add "default.html" as a valid default document.  Now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

can you try going to

```
    http://teorikolarak.com/
```